# Why does my view code use both an instance variable and a local variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables, local-variables

I am looking at a book example. In the view section for a Products model, I see some code like this:

```
<table>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle ('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even') %>">
      <td>
        <%= image_tag(product.image_url, class: 'list_image' %>
      </td>
    <td class ="list_description ">
       <dl>
           <dt> <%= product.title %> </dt>
```

Notice at the top it is using *@products*, while the last line in the table uses *products* instead of *@products*. Can someone explain this a little more?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, *@products* is a collection that responds to the [Enumerator#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) method. In practice, this generally means an Array. You are then iteratively passing each element of *@products* into a block as the *product* variable.

In other words, *product* is a singular element taken from *@products* while executing a loop.

Answer (score 1):

@products contains a collection of Product objects. The product variable contains one instance of Product.

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of variables in Ruby:

- Regular variables, only available in their scope `product` in your sample code
- Instance variables, available in a particular instance of a class. Each instance has its own sets of instance variables, `@products` in your example
- Class variables, available in *all* instances of a class. These are also accessible directly (without an instance), `@@variable` (you do not have an example of this type)

The last line says `product` and is a completely different variable than `@products`. `@products` is filled by the class instance of your controller (probably called `ProductsController`). It is an list of products and the `each()` method is used to iterate through each list item. In the iteration loop `product` is used to specify the current product that is being iterated.

Answer (score 1):

in the context of controllers and views you declare instance variables (starting with an @-symbol) in the controller to pass them to the views.

variables without an @-symbol at the beginning are variables that are only available within a limited scope, for example the elements of an iteration.

so you pass your @products from the controller to the views. after that you can iterate through the elements using product as a temporary identifier for the elements of your @products variable.